# How to append datetime in filename in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to append datetime in filename in below command:

```
COPY (select  query) To '/tmp/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I want my filename like test_date_tim.csv.

Comment: How are you running the COPY command? From psql in command line? Linux environment? By hand or on a script?

Comment: psql command line. But if you can provide the solution for both that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using psql via bash command line, you can simply do:

```
psql -c "COPY (select  query) To '/tmp/test_`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"`.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```